# No error, no display after moving web server to UBUNTU 20,04 (from 8.04.4 UBUNTU version)

Tags: php, apache

I am moving a web server from its ancient Ubuntu 8.04 server to a new platform running Ubuntu 20.  This server has /www/htdocs as its top level for documents, and /www/cgi-bin as its cgi-bin directory.  I have copied the /var/www/html/index.html file to /www/htdocs/apache-index.html

Now, when I access http://servername/apache-index.html from a browser, I get the standard "it works" page, as expected.  At that point, Apache's access shows:

```
"GET /apache-index.html HTTP/1.1" 200 3477 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.182 Safari/537.36"
```

But when I access http://servername/index.php, I get a blank page on the browser, and the access log shows:

```
"GET /index.php HTTP/1.1" **500** 224 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.182 Safari/537.36"
```

I do understand that 500 indicates some sort of internal server error, but I don't find any information that will help me understand what's causing the 500

There is no change in the error log (and here's a "tail" of that) :

```
[Thu Feb 18 09:01:41.322396 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 715] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Feb 18 09:01:41.441212 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1667] AH00163: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Feb 18 09:01:41.441267 2021] [core:notice] [pid 1667] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Feb 18 09:03:35.983538 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1667] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Feb 18 09:03:42.842917 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 724] AH00163: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Feb 18 09:03:42.876278 2021] [core:notice] [pid 724] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Early on, I had gotten an error about not finding a required PHP function but I fixed that by adding include_path to the php.ini file in /etc/php/7.4/apache2

I will be happy to provide configuration files if requested but at this point I am baffled as to where to look.  I would expect some sort of log with that 500 returncode but I don't find anything.

```
/var/log/apache2   02/18 09:33:43
> ls -l
total 24
-rw-r----- 1 root adm 10671 Feb 18 09:34 access.log
-rw-r----- 1 root adm 11400 Feb 18 09:33 error.log
-rw-r----- 1 root adm     0 Feb 17 16:09 other_vhosts_access.log
```

Can you please help me understand where I need to look for additional information?  Thanks@

Comment: Have you checked the PHP configuration, whether that is set to log errors to begin with? (Would be uncommon if it was set not to, but you never know.)

Comment: @CBroe - it's been too long since I did a from-scratch PHP Apache installation.  You have led me to the answer.  I turned on display_errors and that revealed the answer to me (ereg_replace was deprecated at PHP6 and removed at PHP7).  As to why no log was written, I'm still looking into that.  But I can say the ini file amazingly had this at the top: ; log_errors
;   Default Value: Off